# my .sh script for PGO client setup show error of invalid value?

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, pgo

When I run .sh script I see this error

```
error: error executing template "{{.data.username | base64decode }}:{{.data.password | base64decode}}": template: output:1:19: executing             "output" at <base64decode>: invalid value; expected string
error: error executing template "{{ index .data \"tls.crt\" | base64decode }}": template: output:1:27: executing "output" at <base64deco            de>: invalid value; expected string
error: error executing template "{{ index .data \"tls.key\" | base64decode }}": template: output:1:27: executing "output" at <base64deco            de>: invalid value; expected string
```

**This is the script**

```bash
# Use the pgouser-admin secret to generate pgouser file
kubectl get secret -n "${PGO_OPERATOR_NAMESPACE}" "${PGO_USER_ADMIN}" \
  -o 'go-template={{.data.username | base64decode }}:{{.data.password | base64decode }}' > $OUTPUT_DIR/pgouser
# ensure this file is locked down to the specific user running this
chmod a-rwx,u+rw "${OUTPUT_DIR}/pgouser"


*# Use the pgo.tls secret to generate the client cert files
kubectl get secret -n "${PGO_OPERATOR_NAMESPACE}" pgo.tls \
  -o 'go-template={{ index .data "tls.crt" | base64decode }}' > $OUTPUT_DIR/client.crt
kubectl get secret -n "${PGO_OPERATOR_NAMESPACE}" pgo.tls \
  -o 'go-template={{ index .data "tls.key" | base64decode }}' > $OUTPUT_DIR/client.key
# ensure the files are locked down to the specific user running this
chmod a-rwx,u+rw "${OUTPUT_DIR}/client.crt" "${OUTPUT_DIR}/client.key"


echo "pgo client files have been generated, please add the following to your bashrc"
echo "export PATH=${OUTPUT_DIR}:\$PATH"
echo "export PGOUSER=${OUTPUT_DIR}/pgouser"
echo "export PGO_CA_CERT=${OUTPUT_DIR}/client.crt"
echo "export PGO_CLIENT_CERT=${OUTPUT_DIR}/client.crt"
echo "export PGO_CLIENT_KEY=${OUTPUT_DIR}/client.key"
```

I don't see any error, any suggestion Please.

**What I want it to do:**

It should create PGO client and not show any error.

**Edited Question:**

This how I created secret

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry pgo.tls -n pgo --docker-server='https://index.docker.io/v1/' --docker-username='tauqeerdocker' --docker-email='myeamil@gmail.com' --docker-password='Letstest'
```

Comment: This question would benefit from having a [mcve]. The errors you're getting from `kubectl` suggest that the secret you're fetching doesn't actually have the keys you're referencing, but without seeing the actual secret manifest that's just guesswork. Those commands run correctly for me locally when I create appropriate secrets, so it's not an issue in your template syntax.

Comment: Thanks for this  comment, I did create a secret and also create a new user and new secret.  Let me reset all and redo it.

Comment: Hi Can you please write how did you create secrets for this file ? It will be really great help .

Comment: I already edited the Question and code how I created the secrets. I faced the same error. I didn't find any other way to create secrets.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Let me take a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a secret like this:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry pgo.tls \
  -n pgo \
  --docker-server='https://index.docker.io/v1/' \
  --docker-username='tauqeerdocker' \
  --docker-email='myeamil@gmail.com' \
  --docker-password='Letstest'
```

Then you end up with a resource that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: pgo.tls
  namespace: pgo
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6eyJodHRwczovL2luZGV4LmRvY2tlci5pby92MS8iOnsidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ0YXVxZWVyZG9ja2VyIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJMZXRzdGVzdCIsImVtYWlsIjoibXllYW1pbEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJhdXRoIjoiZEdGMWNXVmxjbVJ2WTJ0bGNqcE1aWFJ6ZEdWemRBPT0ifX19
```

When you run:

```
kubectl get secret -n pgo pgo.tls \
  -o 'go-template={{ index .data "tls.crt" | base64decode }}'
```

You're asking for the key `tls.crt` from the `data` attribute, but there is no such attribute. You've created a docker registry secret, not a TLS secret.

If you have a certificate and key available locally, you can create a TLS secret like this:

```
kubectl -n pgo create secret tls \
  --cert=tls.crt --key=tls.key
```

This gets you:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: ...
  tls.key: ...
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: pgo.tls
  namespace: pgo
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

And when we try your command using that secret, it works as expected:

```
$ kubectl get secret -n pgo pgo.tls \
  -o 'go-template={{ index .data "tls.crt" | base64decode }}'
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I managed to create certificates and then create secrets as you mentioned. Now TLS and pgouser is fixed but still have the issue [   error: error executing template "{{.data.username | base64decode }}:{{.data.password | base64decode}}": template: output:1:19: executing             "output" at <base64decode>: invalid value; expected string   ]. Not sure how to fix this?  Do I need a new secret for username?

Comment: Please update your question to show the exact command you're running to create the secret, followed by the exact command that's throwing that error message.